# jQuery .parent() from an li:nth-child(xy)

Tags: jquery, parent, css-selectors

I hope to find help here, I am stuck.

I use this function to get the exact active li element in a menu (with nth-child):

```
function getElementPathWithJquery(element) {
    return $(element).parents().andSelf().map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var entry = '';        
        if(this.nodeName === "BODY" || this.nodeName === "HTML") {
        // do nothing
        } else {
        entry += this.nodeName;
        if (this.className) entry += "." + this.className.replace(/ /g, '.');
        if (this.id) entry += "#" + this.id;
        if ($this.siblings(entry).length > 0) entry += ":nth-child(" + $this.prevAll(entry).length + ")";
        }
        return entry;
    }).get().join(" ");
}
```

Now, being at the requested level, the parent li-element shall get a addClass('active') attribute, but the following does not work:

```
if( $('#MENU_MAIN').find("ul.menu-level-3>li").hasClass('active')) {
var path = getElementPathWithJquery($('#MENU_MAIN').find("ul.menu-level-3>li.active"));
$(path).parent().parent().css('border','3px solid red');
}
```

The reason why I need the exact nth element is the fact that the menu system is a category system an one entry can actually belong to more categories. a solution like:

```
$('#MENU_MAIN').find("ul.menu-level-3>li.active").parent().parent().css('border','3px solid red');
```

works, but depending on the number of categories the found entry belongs to, more than just one parent li could have a red border.

Thanks for your help!
Regards,
Robert

Comment: I should clarify: The path is found correctly, but the .parent().parent() chain appended to $(path) won't yield any results...

Comment: Why are you trying to decode a CSS selector from an element you've just resolved by using a CSS selector?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that stupidity yesterday night... hmm... but how can I put it back into a CSS selector from here and then go up 2 steps in the hiearchy like SELECTED_AGAIN.parent().parent().css(doSomthing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to get all element's ancestors; you can use a selector to limit the results.